# Normilsation - 2NF and 3NF

Tags: schema, normalization

I've been through several questions and youtube tutorials, i understand that 2NF is removing the partial dependencies and 3NF is the transitive ones, but i can't get my head around how the following example should look like in 2NF.

studentID | studentName | courseCode | courseTitle | modCode | modTitle | credits | resultCode

My attempt is the following for 2NF:

**Student**

studentID | studentName | courseCode | modCode | resultCode

**Course**

courseCode | courseTitle

**Module**

modCode | modTitle | credits

*Is this correct? if not where am i going wrong and why.*

---

The following is the 3NF:

**Student**

studentID | studentName | courseCode

**Course**

courseCode | courseTitle

**Module**

modCode | modTitle | credits | courseCode

**Results**

studentID | modCode | resultCode

*Same goes for this, is this correct - if not where and why?*

---

Any help would be great as i've been going over this topic for days now and still not quite sure! Thank you.

Comment: Can you also add the requirement as well, will be easy to understand the design for anyone.

Comment: @vijayp how do you mean by the requirement? - i think it's simply just retrieve student details, what course they are on, what modules are within that course and what result the student received on specific modules. -- its just an example so can be anything tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29772759/2534472

Ok, let's have a look at your 2NF attempt:

> **Student**
>
> studentID | studentName | courseCode | modCode | resultCode
>
> **Course**
>
> courseCode | courseTitle
>
> **Module**
>
> modCode | modTitle | credits

Let's talk about **Student** first.

Your key cannot be studentID, because the resultCode depends on studentID and courseCode (you have one result for every course). But your studentName depends only on studentID, so a part of the key (studentID,courseCode). So 2NF is violated. You need to do something like this:

**Student**

studentID | studentName | courseCode | modCode

**Course**

courseCode | courseTitle

**Module**

modCode | modTitle | credits

**Result**

studentID | courseCode | resultCode

*But please keep in mind, that this respects the 2NF, but still seems not correct, because modules and courses are now completely unrelated. So try this:*

**Student**

studentID | studentName | modCode

**Module**

modCode | modTitle | credits

**Course**

courseCode | courseTitle | modCode

**Result**

studentID | courseCode | resultCode

A course belongs to a module (a module has many courses) - from my point of view. This is automatically in 2NF (because the key is always just one attribute (except for the result, but there is just one non-key-attribute always depending on both key attributes), so nothing can depend on a "part" of the key). And it is in 3NF, too, because every "physical" entity has it's logical representation in the data model (more a rule of thumb than a formalism).

---

Now let's have a look at your 3NF attempt. I think you've got the module<->course dependency the wrong way round, but let's just concentrate on the normalization.

> **Student**
>
> studentID | studentName | courseCode
>
> **Course**
>
> courseCode | courseTitle
>
> **Module**
>
> modCode | modTitle | credits | courseCode
>
> **Results**
>
> studentID | modCode | resultCode

This is correct 3NF, because there is simply no other key candidate than *the* key itself. So there can't be any transitive dependency.

To clarify this: a key candidate is one of the many minimal sets of possible keys. In your relation you have found at least one key candidate with one element (except for the results relation). So any other key candidate cannot have more than one element. That means, that you can simply look at every single attribute and decide "can this be a key or not?" And in your example you find, that no other attribute can be a key - so it's automatically in 2NF and 3NF.